# Understanding "static" methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My confusion stems from the last line of this code snippet:

```
function Animal(name) {
    Animal.count = Animal.count+1||1;// static variables, use function name "Animal"
    this.name = name; //instance variable, using "this"
}

Animal.showCount = function () {//static method
    alert(Animal.count)
}

Animal.prototype.showName=function(){//instance method
    alert(this.name);
}

var mouse = new Animal("Mickey");
var elephant = new Animal("Haddoop");

Animal.showCount();  // static method, count=2
mouse.showName();//instance method, alert "Mickey"
mouse.showCount();//Error!! mouse.showCount is not a function, which is different from  Java
```

**Question:** Why isn't `mouse.showCount()` a function?

Comment: Because you're putting it on **the** `Animal` object, not **all** Animal objects.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't have static methods in a traditional sense. All you're doing is assigning a function as a property of another function (the constructor). Remember, functions are objects in JS.

So there's no direct relationship between the object instances created from a constructor and the constructor itself. The only* relationship is between the instance and the constructor function's `.prototype` object.

If you were to overwrite the `.prototype` of the constructor, then there wouldn't even be that indirect relationship. So basically the constructor just acted as a temporary "match maker" between its `.prototype` and the new object instance being created. After that, the constructor plays no role.

---

<sub>* The `instanceof` operator makes it seem as though there's a connection, but it's really just comparing the objects in the instance's prototype chain to the `.prototype` object of the constructor, so it's still an indirect relationship and one that can be broken.</sub>

Comment: I wonder what the "traditional sense" of a static method is… it never made sense to me that one could access class methods on instances.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah I'm not much of a classical object oriented programmer but I don't think that in those environments a static method is anything like assigning a function to a property of another function. That's mostly what I was getting at. :-)

Comment: @Bergi Agreed. In Java I would argue that a reason could be that it's the "only" way to allow an instance method to access a static method of the same class without specifying the class name (since `doFoo()` is equivalent to `this.doFoo()` which is instance access). Not that it couldn't be solved differently, but it's about the best argument I could come up with…

Comment: @Lye Fish: Very helpful response.  Cleared up some massive JavaScript confusion.